# Strange behaviour \ang after reinstalling latex

Tags: siunitx

After a new install of my computer (Linux Mint 18) I have installed TeX Live, Texmaker and all the necessary packages (like on the previous PC). But when I compile my document I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
```

The problem is on the `\ang{}`

For example `\ang{180}` give me 180180 instead of 180°

I have included the `siunitx` package with  `\usepackage{siunitx}` like before.
What could it be?

Here a minimal Code that give me the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}  

\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{textcomp}  
\usepackage{gensymb}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}  
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{mdframed}  
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}  
\usepackage{comment}  
\usetikzlibrary{angles,positioning,quotes,decorations.markings}  
\usepackage[italian]{babel}  
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}  
\usetkzobj{all}  

\begin{document} 

\chapter{Mychapter}  
\label{chap:Mychapter}

Some text

\section{Il triangolo}  
\label{sec:il triangolo}  

\textbf{Caratteristica del triangolo:} La somma degli angoli interni corrisponde sempre a \ang{180}.  

\end{document}
```

Here the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@@_number_in_sign_replace:N ...ign_replace_aux:N
#1\@@_number_in_sign_repla...
l.34 ...oli interni corrisponde sempre a \ang{180}
.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
[1
] (./MWE.aux) )
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: We'll need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), probably including `\listfiles`: I have a feeling this might be a support package issue.

Comment: What's the `CPQ` document class? Does the same happen when you replace it with `book`?

Comment: Hi, CPQ is my class, I replaced with book and I get the same problem

Comment: please show the exact error from the log, all the lines from `!` to `?` in a code `{}` section in the question so line breaks preserved, please use the version of the example using `book` class, so people can test the same code.

Comment: @GianCarloDozio That looks like a bug in a previous release of `siunitx`: Can you make a document just _loading_ it and with `\listfiles` in the preamble, and edit into the question the version number of `siunitx` you have?

Comment: Actually, something is very odd: you shouldn't get `@@` even in a dodgy version. I think a full `.log` would be useful: can you mail it to me (`joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk`)

Comment: @Joseph I could solve the problem. To install the packages I have used the  procedure on following https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=170852   But for siunitx I get the following error: siunitx-abbreviations.cfg missing. So I have installed the texlive-science package (sudo apt-get install texlive-science) and after that I get the error: ! Undefined control sequence error.  Now I have deleted the directory /home/giancarlo/texmf/tex/latex/siunitx and I get no more error. Are the instructions in the link not the right way to install packages?

Comment: @GianCarloDozio So you had a 'local' version of `siunitx` in your personal tree? That could cause the issue but without the `.log` file details it's hard to say. If you are using your Linux package manager to install TeX then I'd choose `texlive-full` (or similar): the entire thing tends to be easiest. So in that sense the link you give is correct.

Comment: @GianCarloDozio From what you say I think you had a dodgy local copy of `siunitx.sty` around, but without the `.log` details it's not possible to be sure.